# Ionic/Angular js Parsing JSON data from server

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

How to parse JSON object from server using Ionic/Angular js? This is work for me when loading json from /js folder:

```
var rssApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
rssApp.controller('datas', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
$http.get("js/data.json") // <=== this
  .then(function (response) 
  {
   $scope.dat = response;
  });
}]);
```

but when i load json from webserver,i got blank, this is my code :

```
var rssApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
rssApp.controller('datas', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
$http.get("http://localhost/data.json") //<== this 
  .then(function (response) 
  {
   $scope.dat = response;
  });
}]);
```

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Please could you try to write a demo on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/nJWuXYUHtOdHTML3Qi6l?p=preview this help us to understand your problem better. and could you take a look at your javascript console and let us know if you have errors? Best,

Comment: are u getting data with 'http://localhost/data.json'..???

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you tried to use $resource instead of $http? If you console.log your response, is there anything in it?

Comment: You should get data just by navigating to `http://localhost/data.json` using your browser. If data is returned, it's your front-end. If not, the problem is (probably) in your back-end

Comment: @the_mahasagar yes.. i want to fetch data from server;

Comment: @sjokkogutten from browser, data is return fine, when get data from local js folder inside project, it's success, but when pointed to server, in this case from localhost, data return blank..

Comment: to all.. i think it is because the http://localhost/data.json is on port 80, and ionic use port 8100...! so the data.json should be placed inside www on project...

Comment: I would try with 'data.json' path without 'http://localhost/'

Comment: I agree with @QeiNui, placing it in the app is the best way of going about it, then retrieving it using a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing what you have done so far, i suppose your data is being returned as an array from the webserver since you are getting blank with your code. So, you should assign the **response[0]** to **$scope.dat**.

```
var rssApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
rssApp.controller('datas', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
$http.get("http://localhost/data.json") //<== this 
  .then(function (response) 
  {
   $scope.dat = response[0];
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## First

Angular's `$http` promise response [contains a few properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage).

The data returned from the server would be in the `data` property.

From the Angular docs:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - `data` – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
>     `transform functions.
> - `status` – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - `headers` – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - `config` – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request. 
>     `statusText` – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Also you want to make sure that the endpoint is pointing at the correct resource.
I.e if `data.json` is inside your application file, then the path would be `path/to/data.json`. This should be easy to identify, because you'll get a 404 status code with your response object.

## Solution

So you might want to do something like:

```
var endpoint = "path/to/data.json";
$http.get(endpoint).then(function (response) {
   $scope.dat = response.data;
});
```

### One more thing

Also, if in doubt user `console.debug(response);` which will allow you to inspect the response object.